# Install Costura Fody Without Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, fody, fody-costura

I want to be able to have the features of Costura Fody (merging native assemblies into my executable) but I don't want to have to use "Install-Package Costura.Fody" from Nuget. How can I do this? My ideal solution would be being able to just include some of the source code at https://github.com/Fody/Costura/tree/master/src but I don't understand the inner workings enough to know which files would make this possible nor do I know if further steps would be required to "install" the package.

Comment: Why not just use the package? Also nuget.org has good documentation on how the install process works.

Comment: I maintain Costura. This is a difficult question to answer as Costura is a build time tool, and runs just after the compile step. Your ideal solution is not possible.

Comment: @J.R. Walther: If your intention is to avoid NuGet as a source for every restore operation, you can also download the nupkg and put it in a local directory and configure that as a package source.